# cv2 not found - ubuntu bash on windows 10

Tags: python, opencv

I installed Python 2.7 and opencv-python with pip using ubuntu bash on windows. Everything ran smoothly, but when I tried to run my code, I got a message

```
ImportError: No module named cv2
```

I tried a lot of stuff from different threads on stackoverflow, but nothing seemed to work. I think that the problem may be related with the ubuntu bash for windows 10. Do you have any idea how I can solve this problem?

Comment: Have you tried installing it with the OpenCV prebuilds here? http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/introduction/windows_install/windows_install.html

Comment: Yes, but it didn't help.

Comment: How did you run your code?

Comment: From the ubuntu bash, with the command python script.py.

Comment: Have you tried using idle or any other IDE? Just writing `import cv2`?

Comment: What do you mean by using an IDE? What does the IDE have to do with this?

Comment: I just wondered if the import fails everywhere, as I understood it, the `ImportError` happens within the ubuntu bash. So if it would run with `IDLE` you could have a workaround.